# Network configuration tools for Debian (or ubuntu)

Tags: networking, debian, configuration-management

During the initial Debian setup, we are asked simple questions to configure network interfaces. I would like to know is there are some interactive (but something terminal-based, no X11) tools to do the same but after this initial installation.

For example I would like a tool to configure /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/network/interfaces at once. If not, one can for sure develop a tool like that in a few minutes. I am just curious and do not want to miss something that already exists, like a *"dpkg-reconfigure something"*

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is something wrong with just opening up [/etc/network/interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man5/interfaces.5.html) with your favorite text editor?  It has a pretty simple syntax.  If you install the [resolvconf](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/resolvconf) package you can place your DNS configuration in your /etc/network/interfaces file as well by using the `dns-nameservers` and `dns-search` options.

Comment: nothing wrong with editing /etc/network/interfaces, but if you don't do it regulary it always takes some time to find correct options (like changing mac address). I just wanted to save some time to do more interesting things.

Comment: since it's a simple text file, you could always script it.